Linear matrix equation with stacked matrices and repeated unknowns
I have the following seemingly simple linear matrix equation, where I want to solve for the unknown matrix $K \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times m}$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
K A_0 \\ K A_1 \\ \vdots \\ K A_n
\end{bmatrix}
= \mathbf{P}
$$
Both the collection of $m\times m$ square matrices $\{A_i\}$, and the $np \times m$ (tall) matrix $\mathbf{P}$ are known, and, in particular $\{A_i\}$ satisfies
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_0 \\ A_1 \\ \vdots \\ A_n
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
has full column rank $m$. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to solve for $K$ given this information.
My thoughts so far has to do with re-writing the matrix equation using Kronecker product as
$$
(I_n \otimes K) \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{P} \iff \mathbf{A}^{\mathsf{T}}(I_n \otimes K)^{\mathsf{T}} = \mathbf{P}^{\mathsf{T}}, 
$$
and since $\mathbf{A}$ has full column rank, $\mathbf{A}^{\mathsf{T}}$ has full row rank, so there exists a solution $\mathbf{K}$ to the equation $\mathbf{A}^{\mathsf{T}}\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{P}^{\mathsf{T}}$ for any given $\mathbf{P}$. Then I can try to recover $K$ by "undo-ing" the Kronecker product as in Method to reverse a Kronecker product. However, this seems unnecessarily complicated to me and I feel that I have missed something much simpler. Any ideas would be appreciated!

You can rewrite this as a linear system in the elements of K.

@NicNic8 could you elaborate on how?

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\k{\otimes}  \def\h{\odot}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\Big\| #1 \Big\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
$Partitioning the $P$ matrix as Lee suggests produces a set of $n$ matrix equations which can be vectorized to create a set of vector equations
$$\eqalign{
KA_j=P_j&\qiq &\red{(A_j^T\k I)}\vc K=\green{\vc{P_j}}\qq\{j=1\ldots n\} \\
 &\qiq &\red{M_j}\,x = \green{p_j} \\
}$$
In general, one must solve for the unknown vector $x$ in a least-squares sense, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\min_x\;\sum_{j=1}^n\frac12\,\frob{M_jx-p_j}^2 
 &\qiq \sum_{j=1}^n \LR{M_j^TM_jx - M_j^Tp_j}=0 \\
}$$
Summing over $j$ produces the following matrix and vector variables
$$\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{j=1}^n M_j^TM_j \qq\qq b &= \sum_{j=1}^n M_j^Tp_j
}$$
All that remains is to solve a linear system
(via the Moore-Penrose inverse)
$$\eqalign{
Ax = b \qiq x = A^{\bf+}b \;=\; \vc K \\
}$$
and reshape $\,x\in\R{n^2\times\o}\,$ into the matrix $K\in\R{n\times n}$

Thanks! From $M_jx=p_j$ why can't I just vertically stack the $M_j$ and $p_j$ into a larger linear system $\begin{bmatrix} M_1 \ \vdots \M_n\end{bmatrix} x = \begin{bmatrix} p_1 \ \vdots \p_n\end{bmatrix}$? I don' see why not, except it could potentially be a much larger linear system to solve and less efficient.

@user594147 Let's denote your large system as $Nx=c$, and note that $A=N^TN$ and $b=N^Tc$. This means that $Ax=b$ is just the Normal Equation of the large system. So an equivalent way of writing the least squares solution is $x=N^{\bf+}c.;$

Following up on this, and I'd appreciate your insight: in my case I actually do need to work with the large system $Nx = c$ since I need an actual solution $x$ instead of a least-squares solution; however because $N$ is in general tall with full column rank, the solution $x$ may not exist at all. Is there any other way of rewriting this system to obtain an exact solution, or some solvability conditions on the individual matrices $A_i$ and $P_i$?

Why don't you split up $P$ like this:
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix} P_1 \\ P_2 \\ \vdots \\P_n\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
Then you have a set of linear systems $KA_i = P_i$ for each $i = 1, \dots, n$. Here the $A_i$ are $m \times m$ and both $K$ and $P_i$ are $p \times m$. In general it seems like the desired matrix $K$ will be forced to be the zero matrix, but there are definitely situations where the solution spaces will overlap so that non trivial solutions exist.
EDIT: Lets split it up even more to make the system easier to analyze. Let $k_1,\cdots k_p$ be the columns of $K^T$ and let $p_{i,1},\dots p_{i,p}$ be the columns of $P_{i}^T$. Now we have that for each $j = 1, \dots, p$ and each $i =1,\dots, n$ the matrix vector equation  $A_i^Tk_j = p_{i,j}$ must be solved.
We can also restack our systems so we get one linear system for each one of the $k_j$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} A_1^T \\ \vdots \\ A_n^T \end{bmatrix} k_j = \begin{bmatrix} p_{1,j} \\ \vdots \\ p_{n,j} \end{bmatrix}$$
You can find your solution (if it exists) by doing Gauss Jordan elimination for each $j$.

I agree that this would work, but I'd guess this involves solving another constraint satisfaction/optimization problem? Not to say the "reverse Kronecker" method doesn't though... Do you have any insights on the computational complexity of this?
